# How to check chekbox of correspoding node in Treeview control from codebehind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I want to know how Can I check the checkbox of a  asp.net tree view node ( it can be either parent or child) based on matching a condition from the code behind?First Im getting all the nodes from the database. After that I want to check the checkbox corresponding to the ID which that user is a part of.

I hope i'm able to explain my requirement clearly.

Comment: You should accept one of these answers or provide feedback if they did not help.

Answer (score 2):

DataSet dt = objUserClient.GetAllUserClientGroupDetails(UserId);

```
        foreach (TreeNode parent in TreeView1.Nodes)
        {
            foreach (TreeNode child in parent.ChildNodes)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dt.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (child.Value.Trim() == dt.Tables[0].Rows[j]["ClientId"].ToString().Trim())
                    {
                        child.Checked = true;
                        parent.Checked = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Page_Load event, put the following code:

```
TreeNode node = myTreeView.nodes[1];
nodes.Checked = true;
```

This will check the checkbox in the second node.  There are other ways to find the node such as myTreeView.FindNode(path) or by enumerating through the nodes with a foreach loop.  I can provide more info if you specify how you are identifying which notes need to be checked.

Answer (score 1):

```
    //Consider the below dataset holds data
     DataSet dsItemsFind = new DataSet();
    //Use Looping to browse through the Treeview and DataTable
    for (int i = 0; i < Treeview1.Nodes.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dsItemsFind.Tables[0].Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            if (Treeview1.Nodes[i].Value.ToString() == dsItemsFind.Tables[0].Rows[j]["ColumnName"].ToString())
            {
                //If ur Treeview Node value is = the Column value your looking for
                //Then the Below line will get called
                Treeview1.Nodes[i].Checked=true;                   
            }
        }
    }
```